# How to Process Items Downloaded Through a WebBrowser Control?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, webbrowser-control

I know that it is possible to see every item downloaded by the Internet Explorer Webbrowser control through Application Passthrough Protocol. I'm doing that now, but all I seem to have access to is metadata about the item (name, content type, etc.). I've been asked if we can also scan the content of each item.

Can this be done through the webbrowser control's interface? Can it be done through APP?

If it can, can you give me a breakdown of the steps involved, including the names of interfaces that must be queried for?

How will it work if the item is cached?

How will it work if the browser holds the item in memory? Does it ever do so?

Please note that I'm not refering to just the top-level document that is initially fetched, but every item that gets fetched as a result of loading the top-level document (or documents in the case of frames). Every .css, .js, .jpg, etc.

I've also been asked if we can do the same for "outbound network traffic". I'm not even sure what that means, but I assume they mean looking at the outgoing GET requests, headers, and cookies.

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks for the title edit, yours is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the APP. The transaction handler calls your implementation of IInternetProtocol::Read. The pattern is that of a "Pluggable MIME Filter", but since I've already got a passthrough APP, I can just listen in on the Read calls to scan content. This works for cached items because WinInet deals with caching below the APP level.